# Take differences of columns conditional on being associated to others (in R)

Tags: r, date, difference

```
  id hire_month sep_month wage_jan wage_feb wage_mar wage_apr
1  1          2         3      740      780      780      780
2  1          4         0      890      890      890      890
3  2          3         5      550      550      550      550
4  2          5        10      890      250      250      400
  wage_may wage_jun wage_jul wage_aug wage_sep wage_oct wage_nov
1      780      780      780      780      780      780      780
2      890      890      890      890      890      790      250
3      550      550      550      550      550      550      550
4      500      890      600      750      890      300      300
  wage_dec
1      780
2      300
3      550
4      300

structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), hire_month = c(2L, 4L, 
3L, 5L), sep_month = c(3L, 0L, 5L, 10L), wage_jan = c(740L, 890L, 
550L, 890L), wage_feb = c(780L, 890L, 550L, 250L), wage_mar = c(780L, 
890L, 550L, 250L), wage_apr = c(780L, 890L, 550L, 400L), wage_may = c(780L, 
890L, 550L, 500L), wage_jun = c(780L, 890L, 550L, 890L), wage_jul = c(780L, 
890L, 550L, 600L), wage_aug = c(780L, 890L, 550L, 750L), wage_sep = c(780L, 
890L, 550L, 890L), wage_oct = c(780L, 790L, 550L, 300L), wage_nov = c(780L, 
250L, 550L, 300L), wage_dec = c(780L, 300L, 550L, 300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I would like to take the differences between wages based on hire_month and lag(sep_month) -- separation month for the previous row and same id.
For example, if lag(sep_month) is 4 (april) and hire_month is 7 (july), I would like to take the differences between wage_jul and wage_apr (wage_apr being the one on the previous row). So the wages I need to take differences between are actually in different rows, because each row in my dataset is a contract.

I have a large dataset, so I would like a way to automate this association.

Comment: Hire month is later than sep month?????

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it and made a slight modification to my question.

Comment: Second line still has same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated

The OP clarified that the sep month value comes from the row above, which means that there are n-1 rows for each ID, where n is the number of rows for that ID. In the example above, there are two rows per ID, we will estimate the difference for the 2nd (and last) row only for each ID

```
data$diff = as_tibble(data) %>%
  mutate(sep_wage = apply(.,1,function(x) x[x[3]+3])) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(sep_wage = lag(sep_wage)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  apply(.,MARGIN = 1, function(x) x[x[2]+3] - x[16])
```

Output

```
  id hire_month sep_month wage_jan wage_feb wage_mar wage_apr wage_may wage_jun wage_jul wage_aug wage_sep wage_oct wage_nov wage_dec diff
1  1          2         3      740      780      780      780      780      780      780      780      780      780      780      780   NA
2  1          4         0      890      890      890      890      890      890      890      890      890      790      250      300  110
3  2          3         5      550      550      550      550      550      550      550      550      550      550      550      550   NA
4  2          5        10      890      250      250      400      500      890      600      750      890      300      300      300  -50
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I realized though that I needed the difference for hire_date and lagged sep_date within the same id. Could you help me with that please? So the wages I need to take differences between are actually in different rows, because each row in my dataset is a contract.

Comment: Okay, I've made an edit. Basically, I group by ID, and create a new column called `prior_sep`, which is the `sep_month` from the previous row. I then use `relocate` to move that new column into the original location of the `sep_month` column (i.e. move it to column 3, after `id` and `hire_month`, and then run the same `apply` as before, with a slight adjustment for indexing (because now there is an `id` column at the front). The result is assigned to diff..

Comment: Simplified.. not need for the relocate, or new variable

Comment: Thank you! The output is a bit off though. E.g. the last row was expected to return -50, I guess. Because on row 4, hire_month is 5 (associated with wage_may = 500) and lag(sep_month) on row 3 is 5 (associated with wage_may = 550).

Comment: okay, I struggled with this a bit sorry., Now I realize my problem.

Comment: sorry for all the back and forth. I was confused - Perhaps next time also show your expected output, as I didn't realize what the output should look like. Hopefully this does it for you. I have a difference of 110 for id=1, and -50 for id=2

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help! I will provide expected output next time. Since I am new to R, i would like to ask you if you could briefly explain what the following bits of code do?
apply(.,1,function(x) x[x[3]+3])) 
function(x) x[x[2]+3] - x[16])
My original dataset has more variables and I would like to make sure that I can replicate for it. Thank you a lot!